# Вроде всё правильно, а выдаёт, что неправильный синтаксис

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-faq

Что не так с этим кодом?

```
a = input("Введи первое число: ")
```

Ругается именно на эту строчку.

Comment: Конкретно в этой строчке ошибок синтаксиса нет. Не закрыли скобку на предыдущей строке.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, проверил и заработало

Comment: @МихаилМуругов как Вам удалось узнать что скобка не закрыта? Кода ведь автор вопроса не приводил. Или это из разряда об ошибке в 47 строке?

Comment: @V.March Телепатия :) На самом деле это очень распространённая ошибка, рискнул так уверенно предположить.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов  Да, такое бывает, когда чувствуешь код как живой))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень распространённая ошибка из-за невнимательности. Забыли закрыть скобку на **предыдущей** строке.

---

### Почему показало на эту строку?

Потому что синтаксический анализатор ожидает продолжения лексемы внутри открытой скобки, но, т.к. продолжение лексемы находится на новой строке, то ошибка указывает именно на неё.
Для примера:

```py
>>> print(1
... print(2)
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print(2)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Без переноса строки:

```py
>>> print(1 print(2)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(1 print(2)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Просто получается конструкция вида `value print(...`, но, т.к. в питоне нет таких синтаксических конструкций, то мы получаем соответствующую ошибку.

---

В приведённой Вами строке

```py
a = input("Введи первое число: ")
```

синтаксически всё правильно.

Answer (score -3):

Нужно написать так:

```
a = int(input("Введите первое число"))
```

Comment: а что так писать неправильно ? `a = input("Введи первое число: ")`

Comment: Расширьте Ваш ответ. Почему нужно делать именно так?

Comment: Нет, нужно писать `a = float(input("Введите первое число: "))`

Comment: @Эникейщик, слишком узко. `a = complex(input("Введите первое число"))`

Comment: `a = eval(input("Введите первое число"))` 