# в чем ошибка ? выдает синтаксическую ошибку в 43 строке return process_anfisa(elements[1]) , отступы правильные

Tags: python, строки, функции

Код

```
process_anfisa(elements[1]
1
DATABASE = {
2
    'Серёга': 'Омск',
3
    'Соня': 'Москва',
4
    'Миша': 'Москва',
5
    'Дима': 'Челябинск',
6
    'Алина': 'Красноярск',
7
    'Егор': 'Пермь',
8
    'Коля': 'Красноярск'
9
}
10
​
11
# Новая функция, она возвращает правильное словосочетание, склоняя слово "друзья" 
12
# в зависимости от того, какое число передано в аргументе friends_count
13
def format_friends_count(friends_count):
14
    if friends_count == 1:
15
        return '1 друг'
16
    elif 2 <= friends_count <= 4:
17
        return f'{friends_count} друга'
18
    else:
19
        return f'{friends_count} друзей'
20
​
21
​
22
def process_anfisa(query):
23
    if query == 'сколько у меня друзей?':
24
        count = len(DATABASE)
25
        # Вызовите функцию format_friends_count() и передайте в неё count.
26
        # Отредактируйте строку ниже: в ней должно использоваться выражение, 
27
        # которое вернёт функция format_friends_count()
28
        format_friends_count(count)
29
        return f'У тебя {format_friends_count(count)}.'
30
    elif query == 'кто все мои друзья?':
31
        friends_string = ', '.join(DATABASE)
32
        return f'Твои друзья: {friends_string}'
33
    elif query == 'где все мои друзья?':
34
        unique_cities = set(DATABASE.values())
35
        cities_string = ', '.join(unique_cities)
36
        return f'Твои друзья в городах: {cities_string}'
37
    else:
38
        return '<неизвестный запрос>'
39
def process_query(query):
40
    elements  = query.split(', ')
41
    if elements[0]=='Анфиса':
42
        process_anfisa(elements[1]    
43
        return process_anfisa(elements[1])
44
​
45
print('Привет, я Анфиса!')
46
print(process_query('Анфиса, сколько у меня друзей?'))
47
print(process_query('Анфиса, кто все мои друзья?'))
48
print(process_query('Анфиса, где все мои друзья?'))
49
print(process_query('Анфиса, кто виноват?'))
50
print(process_query('Соня, ты где?'))
```

Comment: В предыдущей строке 42 не закрыта скобка: `process_anfisa(elements[1]`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вроде всё правильно, а выдаёт, что неправильный синтаксис](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1066612/1365)

Comment: :Жалко я раньше не сообразил, что дубликат, переголосовать уже не могу

Comment: @CrazyElf так и я вариантом закрытия промахнулся, а мог одним голосом как дубликат закрыть)